# Android Room Generating Dynamic Tables

Tags: android-room

I have a table for users. The user creates a category, and then assigns Youtube videos to the category. I currently have a user table, category table (user-id foreign key), and youtubevideo table (user-id foreign key, category foreign key).

I currently query the category and youtubevideo for the user's id, but I assume these queries could become burdensome as the database grows.

I would instead like to dynamically create a unique table for each user's category based off the user's id, e.g. User 52 has table - category-52, and youtubevideos-52. Is this possible or feasible with Room?

Answer (score 7):

It is not, `Room` generates schema using `annotations`. Annotations are processed before compilation using `annotationProcessors`. Because of this it is not possible to generate tables at runtime.

Comment: It's bad news, but it looks like the truth.

Comment: It should be possible， see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556803/how-to-create-a-new-table-in-room-dynamically